# How to return JSON objects (List of Dictionaries) in Flask API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask, flask-restful

Newbie here and stuck on returning some objects from JSON to my Flask API.

I have a list of dictionaries called data, you'll see in my code below. I need to check if the status_id is in the data. If it is, I have to display that user's name. How would I access a dictionary from a list? Or is my json not valid? I did use a linter to check and it passed the JSON test. I'm getting error: string indices must be integers. Which leads me to believe that since it's a list I'll need integers for the indexes.

Any help in the right direction would be great.

Here's my code:

```
@app.route("/status/<status_id>", methods=['GET'])
def get_status(status_id):
    data = [{
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Meghan"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Julia"
            }
        ]

    data_dump = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

    if status_id in data_dump:
        #find that status id and name and return it
        return data_dump[status_id]['name']
    else:
        return "Not Found in Dictionary"
```

Comment: `json.dumps` turns `data` into a `str` representation of your `dict` as json.  Use `data` for your comparison logic (since `data` is a `dict`) not `data_dump` (which is a `str`).

Comment: Also your `data` does not contain a key `'status_id'`, did you mean to do `return data_dump[status_id]['name']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below. A simplified version of the `get_status` function.

Pay attention to the HTTP status code (200 Vs. 404)

```
@app.route("/status/<status_id>", methods=['GET'])
def get_status(status_id):
    data = [{
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Meghan"
    },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Julia"
        }
    ]
    name = None
    for entry in data:
        if entry['id'] == status_id:
            name = entry['name']
            break
    if name is not None:
        print('The name for status_id {} is {}'.format(status_id,name))
        return name, 200
        # or, if you want to return both use Flask jsonify and send a dict
        # see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.json.jsonify
    else:
        print('Can not find a name for status id {}'.format(status_id))
        return "Not Found in Dictionary", 404
```

Comment: Hi! I like your simplified version but am getting `"Not Found in Dictionary", 404` when going to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/status/5`.

Comment: @newcoder I have added debug print that will help you to see what is going on. See the updated code.

Comment: k, thanks for the debug statements. I get `Can not find a name for status id 5`, still stepping through my code.

Comment: When I do this: `if entry['id'] == 5:` it displays the correct output

Comment: k, this works: `if entry['id'] == int(status_id):` thanks for the help! Ill mark your answer as correct.

Comment: It may be that the ststus_id you get is a string and not int.

Comment: see here how to get an int. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#variable-rules

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems like you want to return the name of the object where `id == status_id`. Is that right? Than you don't have to dump it to json. You can check if the `status_id` exists in the list with:

```
len(list(filter(lambda x: x['id'] == status_id, data))) == 1
```

Explanation:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x['id'] == status_id, data))
```

This filters your list of dictionaries to only have these dictionaries that have the matching id.

```
len(...) == 1
```

This checks if there is only and and exactly one object that has this id. If you want to return the name of exactly that dict you could write it like that:

```
matching_dict = list(filter(lambda x: x['id'] == status_id, data))
if len(matching_dict) == 1:
    return matching_dict[0]['name']
```

And if you then want to return json (as a string). Then you have to call `json.dumps()` like `json.dumps(matching_dict[0])` depending on whatever you want to do.

**Edit**: So putting all together it could look like that:

```
@app.route("/status/<status_id>", methods=['GET'])
def get_status(status_id):
    data = [{
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Meghan"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Julia"
            }
        ]

    matching_dict = list(filter(lambda x: x['id'] == status_id, data))
    if len(matching_dict) == 1:
        return json.dumps(matching_dict[0])
    else:
        return "Found zero or more than one in Dictionary"
```

Request: `GET /status/5`

Response: `{"id":5, "name": "Meghan"}`

Comment: Ok thank you! I have to ultimately display the json for each user id in my api in order to do a GET request. Is that where I'd use json.dumps?

Comment: Added complete code. You have to call json.dumps if you want to convert the dict Python object into plain string. That is isually what happens at last when returning the result.

Comment: Ok thanks! When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/status/5` I get `Found zero or more than one in Dictionary`

Comment: L3n95 - your code iterate over all entries in `data`. This may be expansive if there will be many entries in data..

Comment: @balderman yes that's true. @newcoder than you have no matching user or more than one. You could print `matching_dict` for debugging that